# Firebase DB copying data one node to another

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to add data from one node in my database (groups/groupId/matches) to another node (users/userId/groups)

This method executes once perfectly, but if I try to execute a second time I run in to trouble, getting this error

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: 
Failed to convert value of type java.lang.String to boolean
```

From using Firebase I undestand that SetValue you should overwrite any existing data and I have seen this in my app

Just not sure of my next move and any help is much appreciated.

Method call

```
  moveFirebaseRecord(groupsDatabase.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("matches"),
                            usersDatabase.child(uId).child("groups"));
```

Method

```
    public void moveFirebaseRecord(DatabaseReference fromPath, final DatabaseReference toPath) {
    fromPath.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            toPath.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue(), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    if (databaseError != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "COPY FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "COPY SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onCancelled- copy fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"This method executes once perfectly..." is the intended behavior of [`addListenerForSingleValueEvent`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)). From the docs:

> Add a listener for a single change in the data at this location. This listener will be triggered once with the value of the data at the location.

[`addValueEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) sounds more appropriate for this case.

If you always need to copy data written from `groups/groupId/matches` into `users/userId/groups` it might be better to use a [Firebase Cloud Function with a Realtime Database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jeff, I tried it with addValueEventListener and same error is occurring . 
I will have a look at cloud functions to solve this , is it advisable to us cloud functions to check if data exists in a node and if not to copy it over?

Comment: Yes, cloud functions sound like a good solution here. Where in your app is your `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: 
Failed to convert value of type java.lang.String to boolean` coming from? Which line is causing it?

Comment: I'm not sure which line is causing it or why it works the first time and not after subsequent tries (even when I use addValueEventListener ) 
There are 2 Boolean values in my Match class which would be getting copied over . So maybe it is one of these causing issue. It's not very clear when I try logging the values in my method to the console

Comment: From logging to console it actually looks like the method doesn't get started at all as nothing is being logged in the console

Comment: Are your values definitely being saved as booleans? Perhaps they are being saved as strings and whatever is consuming this data expects a boolean.